# Multithreading in Java with 3 threads

Tags: java, multithreading

I am trying to create a multithreaded program of the below program to compute Pi. My simple program is:

```
  import java.util.Random;

  public class MonteCarloPi {
    static Random generator = new Random( System.currentTimeMillis() );
    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {

            long N = 10000000;
            if ( args.length > 1 )
                    N = Long.parseLong( args[0] );

            double PI = myPiCompute(N);

            System.out.println( N + " random samples yield an approximation of Pi = " + PI);

    }


    public static double myPiCompute (long N){
        long Nc = 0;
            for ( long i=0; i<N; i++ ) {
                    float x = generator.nextFloat()*2 - 1; // random float in [-1,1]
                    float y = generator.nextFloat()*2 - 1; // random float in [-1,1]
                    if ( x*x + y*y <= 1.0f )
                            Nc += 1;
            }

            double PI = 4.0*Nc/N;
            return PI;
    }

}
```

Now, I am trying to make it multithreaded (atleast 3 threads). So I am doing the following but getting errors.

```
 import java.util.Random;

   class MyThread implements Runnable {
    /**
     * @param args
     */
    static Random generator = new Random( System.currentTimeMillis() );
        public void run() {
            System.out.println("this thread is running ... ");
            long N = 10000000;
            if ( args.length > 1 )
                    N = Long.parseLong( args[0] );
            double PI = myPiCompute(N);

            System.out.println( N + " random samples yield an approximation of Pi = " + PI);

        }
    }


    public static double myPiCompute (long N){
        long Nc = 0;
            for ( long i=0; i<N; i++ ) {
                    float x = generator.nextFloat()*2 - 1; // random float in [-1,1]
                    float y = generator.nextFloat()*2 - 1; // random float in [-1,1]
                    if ( x*x + y*y <= 1.0f )
                            Nc += 1;
            }

            double PI = 4.0*Nc/N;
            return PI;
    }




public class MonteCarloPi {

        public static void main(String[] args) {

                MyThread myObject = new MyThread();
                Thread thr1 = new Thread(myObject);
                thr1.start();

                Thread thr2 = new Thread(myObject);
                thr2.start();

                Thread thr3 = new Thread(myObject);
                thr3.start();
    }

  }
```

I am getting the following errors.

```
     MonteCarloPiPar.java:19: error: class, interface, or enum expected
    public static double myPiCompute (long N){
                  ^
    MonteCarloPiPar.java:21: error: class, interface, or enum expected
            for ( long i=0; i<N; i++ ) {
            ^
    MonteCarloPiPar.java:21: error: class, interface, or enum expected
            for ( long i=0; i<N; i++ ) {
                            ^
    MonteCarloPiPar.java:21: error: class, interface, or enum expected
            for ( long i=0; i<N; i++ ) {
                                 ^
     MonteCarloPiPar.java:23: error: class, interface, or enum expected
                    float y = generator.nextFloat()*2 - 1; // random float in [-1,1]
                    ^
    MonteCarloPiPar.java:24: error: class, interface, or enum expected
                    if ( x*x + y*y <= 1.0f )
                    ^
     MonteCarloPiPar.java:26: error: class, interface, or enum expected
            }
            ^
    MonteCarloPiPar.java:29: error: class, interface, or enum expected
            return PI;
            ^
    MonteCarloPiPar.java:30: error: class, interface, or enum expected
    }
    ^
   9 errors
```

I am trying to playaroung with multithreads. Can anybody point me out what I am doing wrong.

Comment: `"I am getting many errors."` -- why not show us the errors? And also the lines that cause them? It would seem the logical thing to do, no?

Comment: First off, count your curly braces, and make sure all opening braces match closing braces.

Comment: You've got an extra closing brace above the error throwing lines.

Comment: Voting to close as typo.

Comment: Agree with @SotiriosDelimanolis-- it's just a careless error.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels can't delete the question as it has more than 1 answer.

Answer (score 0):

You've got an extra closing brace above the error throwing lines.

Here:

```
class MyThread implements Runnable {
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("this thread is running ... ");
        long N = 10000000;
        if ( args.length > 1 )
                N = Long.parseLong( args[0] );
        double PI = myPiCompute(N);

        System.out.println( N + " random samples yield an approximation of Pi = " + PI);

    }
}  // <<< *********
```

Get rid of it, then delete this question. In the future, count your opening and closing braces when this happens.

Comment: Please don't up-vote this answer as it might make the question harder to delete.

Comment: I am getting more errors after fixing it. It's not able to recognize `args` even I provide it in `@param` in `MyThread`.

Comment: @user2481422: start over

Comment: @user2481422: it means that you were careless in creating this code, that you would likely be better off deleting it and starting over again.

Comment: Best advice possible. If you make such a mess of things that you can't even make heads or tails of it yourself anymore, admit defeat, delete the code and start over. This time taking more care. I must have done that a hundred times when I was starting out in school, in the end just tossing your mess away saves a lot of time because you continue to write code you have a grasp on rather than stare blindly at existing code that looks like a foreign language.

Comment: Got it. Sorry cant delete the question.

Answer (score -1):

you "myPiCompute" function isn't in a class.

Comment: Yeah, since everybody is busy criticising it rather than helping me, I have already figured that out and fixed it. Will soon post a answer for my question.

Comment: Not your down-voter, but this question needs to be closed as it won't help anyone in the future for being too specific and just sloppy coding. But please feel free to down-vote my community wiki answer, again so that this question will be more easily closed.

Comment: You've better to use an IDE to help you validating your syntax. ;-)